# Обработка клика вне айтемов RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, android-on-click

Я реализовал выделение айтемов и мне нужно его снимать при клике на один из них или на пустое место под ними.
Если написать просто `rv.setOnClickListener({...})` срабатывать не будет.

Как правильно это реализовать?

**UPD**

```
rv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("RecyclerViewClick","Клик по rv");
        Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, "rv1click", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Приведите ваш код.

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, добавил. Еще что-то?

Comment: [почитайте для начала это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)